# perl tk drag & drop folder from windows explorer

Tags: perl, winapi, drag-and-drop, tk-toolkit, directory

All,

I have a win32 perl TK app i am working on, and to make this simple for the user, I would like drag N drop functionality for folders from windows explorer/desktop onto a widget (eg. textbox etc) in my app.

The reason is to eliminate manual directory/file select dialogs etc.

Some example code would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Jeremy.

Comment: In the Perl/Tk source distribution, there are some sample scripts in the DragDrop directory. Can you check if any of these (e.g. site_test) work for you?

Answer (score 2):

There is the module Tk::DropSite which should work for you.

An example code can be found here: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.tcltk/2010/02/msg375.html

This is a working example code:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use Tk;
use Tk::DropSite;
use Tk::Pane;

my $textVariable = "drag here";

my $mw = MainWindow->new;

my $frame = $mw->Frame(
)->pack(-side => 'top', -expand => 1, -fill => 'x');

$frame->Label(
    -text => "My Label",
    -anchor => 'w',
    -width => 10,
)->pack(-ipady => 1, -side => 'left');

my $entry = $frame->Entry(
    -textvariable => \$textVariable,
    -width => 40,
)->pack(-side => 'left');

$frame->DropSite(
    -dropcommand => [\&AcceptDrop, $frame],
    -droptypes => ('Win32'),
);

$mw->MainLoop;


sub AcceptDrop {
    my ($widget, $selection) = @_;
    my $filename;

    $filename = $widget->SelectionGet(
        -selection => $selection, 
        'STRING'
    );
    $textVariable = $filename;
} # /AcceptDrop
```

If you know German, have a look here: http://www.perltk.de/tk_widgets/howto_perl_tk_tkx_comparison.html