# Perl/Tk Dropsite: Dragging Windows files with arbitrary Unicode names

Tags: perl, unicode, drag-and-drop, tk-toolkit

In a Perl/Tk app I want to drag & drop files with arbitrary unicode filenames onto a widget.

There is this working DropSite example:
[perl tk drag & drop folder from windows explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964361/perl-tk-drag-drop-folder-from-windows-explorer)
but it doesn't work with filenames that contain unicode characters, e.g. cyrillic mixed with German. The special characters (that are not on the local codepage) are received just as "?".

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Somewhere in the chain some component is not UTF-8 capable.

Comment: Yes, Tk::DropSite under Windows, it seems.

Comment: Not quite. Somewhere along the chain, an "A"NSI interface is used instead of a "W"ide interface. So it gets the file names encoded using the process's Active Code Page (possibly cp1252) instead of UTF-16le.

Comment: You could try changing the Active Code Page for your `perl` to UTF-8. [How to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page)

Comment: I used this "working example" I quoted. decode_utf with the result didn't help. If I drag the file "äääüüüФонарь.png" onto the widget the result with decode_utf8 is: 
R:\������??????.png And without it : R:\äääüüü??????.png

Comment: The encoding is given `perl -Mv5.14 -MWin32 "say 'cp'.Win32::GetACP()"`. Makes no sense to use `decode_utf8` (unless that returns cp65001 aka UTF-8)

Comment: To make sure it is the codepage issue. I will look into changing the codepade to UTF-8. That looks like the solution. I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: It'll change it for all of perl. Which means `open`, `opendir`, `stat`, `readdir` will change from your current code page to 65001 (UTF-8). That's probably a good thing.

Comment: I tested this on windows, if I drag a file name with a unicode character like `a€` and prints out the result from `SelectionGet()` with `printf "%vX\n", $filename` it shows as `61.80.2E.74.78.74`, so the `a` was received as hex `61` (normal ascii value) and the `€` was received as the 5 bytes `80.2E.74.78.74` (hex) which is not utf-8 and I am not able determine what encoding this is yet

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, That's `a€.txt` encoded using cp1252.  Nothing was replaced with `?` because every character could be represented by your ACP. See my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft help page Ikegami mentioned, how to [change the Windows code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page), also shows how to change the code page for all of Windows (not just per app):

> go to Windows Settings > Time & language > Language & region > Administrative language settings > Change system locale, and check Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support. Then reboot the PC for the change to take effect.

I did that and it worked fine for me and solved the DropSite problem too. (But you need to decode the received string to utf8.)

So the modified version of the above mentioned working script would then be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::DropSite;
use Encode;

my $textVariable = "drag here";

my $mw = MainWindow->new;

my $frame = $mw->Frame(
)->pack(-side => 'top', -expand => 1, -fill => 'x');

$frame->Label(
    -text => "My Label",
    -anchor => 'w',
    -width => 10,
)->pack(-ipady => 1, -side => 'left');

my $entry = $frame->Entry(
    -textvariable => \$textVariable,
    -width => 40,
)->pack(-side => 'left');

$frame->DropSite(
    -dropcommand => [\&AcceptDrop, $frame],
    -droptypes => ('Win32'),
);

$mw->MainLoop;


sub AcceptDrop {
    my ($widget, $selection) = @_;
    my $filename;

    $filename = decode_utf8 $widget->SelectionGet(
        -selection => $selection, 
        'STRING'
    );
    $textVariable = $filename;
} # /AcceptDrop
```

Comment: Note: I found that if you want to use an utf-8 file name as an argument for Tk::Photo you need to provide it via "encode_utf8" .